# How to install ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services when not using VS 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, blazor

I am learning how to build a Blazor app from [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/22/get-started-building-net-web-apps-in-the-browser-with-blazor/). 
The required tools are given as follows.

- Install the .NET Core 2.1 SDK (2.1.300-preview2-008533 or later).
- Install Visual Studio 2017 (15.7 Preview 5 or later) with the ASP.NET and web development workload selected.
- Install the latest Blazor Language Services extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Because downloading and installing VS 2017 take much time, I just installed the SDK. I also downloaded the language service (`.vsix` file) but don't know how to install it.

The following steps succeeded.

```
md test
cd test


dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
dotnet new blazor -o ba1
cd ba1
```

But the following

```
dotnet run
```

produces an error as follows:

> CSC : error CS1617: Invalid option '7.3' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values. [C:\Users\amd\test\ba1\ba1.csproj]

## Question

It seems I need to install the language service, but how can it be done without VS 2017?

## Edit

For answering the comment why I did not install VS 2017 and assume (I did not assume actually) it optional, see the excerpt taken from the tutorial.

> [image]

Comment: Wouldn't you think there is a reason for that to be a requirement and not an optional step? Of course you cannot install a Visual Studio Extension without Visual Studio

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: No assumption, see my edit question at the bottom part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language service is for intellisense in Visual Studio. So if you are not using Visual Studio there is no need to install it. There is no blazor intellisense support for VSCode right now or something.

See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/871) for the 7.3 error.

Comment: So the solution is just install and use .NET Core 2.1 RC1.

Comment: Yes. or at least 2.1 preview2 -008533. Be aware that 2.1.200 is not good enough.